Construct a finite and injective ring map
Recently I meet a problem in commutative algebra as follows.
Let $k$ be a field, and $A=k[x, y] /(x y-1)$. Find explicity a map
$$
k\left[z_1, \cdots z_n\right] \rightarrow k[x, y] /(x y-1)
$$
which is finite and injective.
I only know $k[x,y]/(xy-1)=(k[x])_x$, but I have no ideal about how to construct this map.

This seems unlikely to be possible for $n>1$ under any reasonable interpretation of the question. Are you sure you have stated the question correctly?

@Hugh Thomas Yes, I also think this is a wrong proposition. I will ask my teacher who assigned this question.

Try $k[z]\to A$, where $z\mapsto x+y$.
